# Change some basic details about document type resume

Tags: spacing, formatting, line-breaking, cv, resume

I am writing my resume and using [template "9b" from this website](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/). However, there are a couple of items that I would like to modify.

Here is the `.tex` file and corresponding screen-shot after compilation.

```
\documentclass[line,margin]{res}
\usepackage{newcent}   
\begin{document}
\name{\huge{Andrew Parker}}

\address{123 M, Main Street, \\ Port Washington, NC, 12345}
\address{www.google.com}
\address{631-231-1232}

\begin{resume}
\section{OBJECTIVE} A position in the field of computers with special 
                interests in business applications programming, 
\section{EDUCATION} {\sl Bachelor of Science,} Interdisciplinary Science \\
                Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute, Troy, NY, 
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Here is the screen-shot after compilation

[image]

1. As you can see, even though my TeX-code mentions my web-site name **www.google.com** 
   the compiler seems to ignore it and skips ahead to the next address line with the phone number. Why does that happen?
2. My mailing address is too long. But when I tried to break the my mailing address into 
   two lines using `\\`, there was no effect. The mailing address still appears all on one line.
3. I would like to include my nationality and visa type just under my name. How would I do it? All the address lines are placed at the extreme right of the page. I would like to place my visa-type and nationality to the left of the page under my name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the entire "address" inside a `tabular`-like structure. Below I've used [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx):

[image]

```
\documentclass[line,margin]{res}
\usepackage{newcent,tabularx}

\begin{document}
\name{\huge Andrew Parker}

\address{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X l l@{}}
  South African      & Address: & 123 M, Main Street, \\ 
  Permanent Resident &          & Port Washington, NC, 12345 \\
                     & Website: & www.google.com \\
                     & Phone:   & 631-231-1232
\end{tabularx}}

\begin{resume}
\section{OBJECTIVE} A position in the field of computers with special 
                interests in business applications programming, 
\section{EDUCATION} {\sl Bachelor of Science,} Interdisciplinary Science \\
                Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute, Troy, NY, 
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```